# Why is Flask's flash message failing to display

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm trying to flash a message then redirect to the home page. But the flash message never appears after being redirected to home page. However `app.logger.debug(get_flashed_messages())` does catch the flash message before redirection.

```
app.secret_key = 'somesecret'

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/add',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == "POST":
        url = request.form['url']
        flash("Stored bookmark " + url)          # Never displays
        store_bookmarks(url)
        app.logger.debug(get_flashed_messages()) # Catches flash message
        return redirect(url_for('index'))        # Always redirects
    return render_template('add.html')
```

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1168 This is the only thing i could find while searching but my `APPLICATION_ROOT` is unmodified

Comment: What's your index.html look like? Are you displaying flashed messages somewhere in your templates?

Comment: @EricWorkman The index page is empty right now other than trying to display messages in flash. Sometimes it displays the message as if it were part of webpage.  index html can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/4a9AjRZT

Comment: @EricWorkman It seems i was confusing web2py and flask. I've got it all figured out now